# 'The' before 'physical properties'

Tags: articles, formal-language

I'm preparing for academic IELTS by writing some essays and then correcting those using a grammar correction app.

In the following sentence,

> ...it relies on physical properties of artificially heated air

The app suggests putting 'the' before 'physical properties'. Why is it so? My logic was the following: I wasn't talking about those properties before, 'artificially heated air' is mentioned like a general idea, so 'physical properties' probably have to be indefinite as well.

Could you please suggest why 'the' is needed here and is it critical for formal writing in this case?

Many thanks!

Comment: Putting the "the" in would be more common. It is correct because artificially heated air has a particular set of properties. Leaving it out would be vague about which properties.

Comment: The 'artificially heated air' isn't a general idea, but a mass noun, and any such air has those properties anyway. They are fixed, not vague.